# How to escape period characters in URL

Tags: go

Good day!

I have a URL, let's say

```
http://someurl.com?someparam=my.dot.param
```

I know period ( "." - symbol) is a valid HTTP query symbol, but for some reasons I need it to be escaped with "%2E"

I wanted to use something like ***EscapedPath()*** but, as I mentioned before, period ( "." - symbol) is a valid HTTP query symbol so I could not do that.

What I did.

1) I remove all periods in string "**my.dot.param**" with some constant (like "_remove_this_dot_")
so I get "**my_remove_this_dot_dot_remove_this_dot_param**"

2) After I get final URL :

```
u.RawQuery = q.Encode()
retURL := u.String()
```

I do

```
result :=  strings.ReplaceAll(retURL, "_remove_this_dot_", "%2E")
```

All works but the code looks awful - is there any way to do it correct? With standard library maybe?

PS Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: It is often the case that awful code is required to work around bugs in network peers.  Simpler code is to replace `.` in the query with the original `my.doc.param` value:  `u.RawQuery = strings.ReplaceAll(q.Encode(), ".", "%2E")`

Comment: Cerise Limón, as I remember - q.Encode() will encode query and % will be encoded. So this is not an option

Comment: My suggested code replaces `.` with `%2E` on the result of `q.Encode()`, not the input to `q.Encode()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awful code is sometimes needed to work around bugs in network peers.

A simpler approach to that in the question is to replace the `.` in the raw query where the raw query is created with the value including `.`.

```
q.Set("someparam", "my.dot.param")
u.RawQuery = strings.ReplaceAll(q.Encode(), ".", "%2E")
result := u.String()
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/V5MJfAATlap).